# Rstudio dual monitoring

Tags: rstudio

Is there a way to display Rstudio's panes on separated windows to display (for example) the source on one screen and the console/environment/misc on the second screen?

I browsed the web quite a while without finding any informations, so it's either really easy or impossible.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I believe the answer is no.  People have been requesting it for a while but I don't believe it's been implemented yet.

Comment: Okay thanks. Should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 1):

This is the one missing feature that keeps me from switching to RStudio. It would be great to be able to separate the source from the console window.